# Android Studio add Music to Background over multiple Activities without repeat

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background

Im trying to implement a Soundfile to the Background of my application, which will play through multiple Activities without stopping and playing it all over again. I found an answer online by using AsyncTask, but it just tells me that my other Class is "not enclosed" Does anyone have a suggestion how i could use it easier or more efficient? I will include the code here:

```
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Splashscreen.this, R.raw.mainmenu);
    //Splashscreen.this is "not an enclosing class"
}
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
    mMediaPlayer.start();
    return null;
}
protected void onCancelled(Void v) {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Splashscreen Code:

```
public class Splashscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private View mContentView;
BackgroundSound mBackgroundSound;

public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}

Thread splashTread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    hide();
    StartAnimations();
    mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mBackgroundSound.execute();

}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mBackgroundSound.cancel(true);
}

private void StartAnimations() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;

                while (waited < 3500) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                        MainMenu.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {
                Splashscreen.this.finish();
            }

        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}
private void hide() {
    mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend to use service instead of AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use service for the job:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_sound_file);
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Start it with intent from your onCreate() method in Splashscreen:

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
svc.setAction("com.example.BackgroundSoundService");
startService(svc);
```

Add BackgroundSoundService to the Manifest.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.idokov.layouttests">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i tried using this code but i couldn't hear any music. I made a Toast at the end of "startService(svc) which was displayed but the function in BackgroundSound gets not called... any tipps on what i might be doing wrong? :/

Comment: You have to do 2 things to start you service: 1. Declare your service into Manifest file. 2. `svc.setAction("path_to_your_service.BackgroundSoundService");`

Comment: Sorry i still don't fully understand what you mean by path_to_your_service am i supposed to reference my structure in a String? Like     setAction("net.campus.pgrunder.splashscreenproject.model.BackgroundSound");

Comment: Yes, exactly. The reference to your structure.

Comment: The Manifest code you sent me, is supposed to go on the very top of my AndroidManifest.xml even above my <application> Tag right?

Comment: I uploaded the manifest file. The service declaration should be at the same level as the activities.

Comment: Can you quickly have a look at what im doing wrong? it always tells me "cannot resolve symbol". http://pastebin.com/JWXgDKf4

Comment: In my case  `<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />` is valid path to the service, in your case probably`<service android:enabled="true" android:name="net.campus.pgrunder.splashscreenproject.model.BackgroundSoundService" />` it depends of your package structure.

Comment: Oh my god it finally works like a charm, thank you so much for helping me out! :) Sorry that i was such a pain to teach :P

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use services for this kind of cross-activity stuff.

The following guide will help you setup your service: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html